# Include a reference in the combination of expression and paste function in R

Tags: r

I want to add a label with mathematical notations and a number reference to my plot. I tried the `expression` function and the `paste` function, but I failed to include what I want to write in my plot.

Here is a easy version of my question:

```
plot(NA,xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0,5))
a = 5
```

At  point (1,1), I want to add a label **γ=5** on the plot. Here is what I tried:

```
text(1,1,expression(paste(gamma, "=", a)))
```

But the plot shows that **γ=a**. 
I am wondering how I can include a number reference in the combination of expression and paste function.

Thank you!

Comment: options in include `substitute` and `bquote`, for example, `text(1,1, bquote(gamma == .(a)))`

Comment: It works!! Thank you!